# My smart phone upgrade

Tags: upgrade

I have my smartphone with Android 4.0.1 version. It is original Chinese brand TOOKY.  Can my phone OS change to Ubuntu? Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer** : No.

---

**Long answer** : Maybe it will become available if :

- One day TOOKY decides to port Ubuntu Touch for your device (most unlikely).
- Xda-developers decide to port it (depending on the popularity of your phone).
- You develop it (it's not as easy to do as to say).

What is sure though, is that for now, Ubuntu Touch is still in development and is only aiming Nexus devices. All other phones and tablets should wait and hope. That's all we know for sure.